# SSAS Cube Errors, Not Deploying Cube and Dimensions

Tags: sql, ssas

I'm getting more errors which are very vague.

Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully.
The following system error occurred:  The user name or password is incorrect. 
Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Accident1', Name of 'Accident1'.
Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'DIM Zone', Name of 'DIM Zone' was being processed.
Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Zone SK' attribute of the 'DIM Zone' dimension from the 'MultidimensionalProject2' database was being processed.
Server: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.

This occurs when I try to deploy the cube to the server.

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Thanks, Madhura

Comment: If you read the error, it's telling you that the user name or password that you used to deploy and process the cube is not valid. Did you perhaps use a service account for a dev environment when you meant to update it to a production account? If not, does the account you used have appropriate permissions on the SSAS instance? Did you mean to deploy but not process?

Comment: yep. That is true, i used SQL server Authentication. So now process the cube.